# Difference between a quadratic residue and a number is a quadratic residue

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

Let $p$ be an odd prime, and let $a\in\mathbb{Z}_p^*$, i.e. $a\not\equiv 0$. Let $q_1,\ldots,q_{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ be the quadratic residues mod $p$. Is there a way of knowing how many $j\leq \frac{p-1}{2}$ satisfy $q_j - a$ is a quadratic residue?

Comment: Do you want to prove that for every $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{*}$ there exist a quadratic residue $q_j$, such that $q_j - a$ is a quadratic residue too?

Comment: I want more, I want to know given $a$ how many $q_j$ satisfy that $q_j - a$ is a quadratic residue